# update value in a column of a table based on input in shiny

Tags: shiny-reactivity

I am new in Shiny and I need yours knowledge. I will try explain with detail:

In my application, the user upload a csv file. This information is visualized in 2 tabPanel. In the first tabPanel named Original, the user can see the original dataset. The other one named Procesado, the user can see a select input with values from 1 to 4 and only 2 columns (internally before to show the information, the dataset is edited, eliminating columns and rows).

I want update the values of the first column every time that the user change the value in the select input. I tried with renderUI and reactive, but is not working. Thanks

```
shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Ciclismo - Calidad de la sesion"),
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Escoge el dataset generado por la aplicacion de ciclismo Polar"),
      fileInput("file1","Escoge un archivo CSV",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c(".csv")),
      tags$hr(),
      
      submitButton("Evaluar Dataset")
      ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Original", tableOutput("contents")),
        tabPanel("Procesado", 
                 p("Selecciona la zona de entrenamiento a evaluar"),
                 selectInput("zone", "Zona de entrenamiento",
                            choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4")),
                 uiOutput("ui"),
                 tags$hr(),
                 tableOutput("modified"),),
        tabPanel("Graficos",
                  h3(textOutput("output_text")),
                  plotOutput("output_plot")
                 )
       
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The code on the server is

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    #data.frame(x=auto)
    req(input$file1)
    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    #tryCatch(
      #{
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
      #},
      #error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
       # stop(safeError(e))
     # }
    #)
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    switch(input$zone, 
            "1" = cbind(ZONA = 1, dfProc),
            "2" = cbind(ZONA = 2, dfProc),
            "3" = cbind(ZONA = 3, dfProc),
            "4" = cbind(ZONA = 4, dfProc))
  })
    
  
  output$modified <- renderTable({
    req(input$file1)
    dff <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    #return(df)
    
    dfN = dff[-c(1,2,3),-c(1,2)]
    FC = dfN[,-c(2:26)]
    #Se convierte en dataframe para realizar operaciones
    dfProc = data.frame(FC)
    
    newdata_test = cbind(ZONA = 1,dfProc)
    return(newdata_test)
  })
  
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it.

I put two eventReactive. The first one is to read the CSV file. The second one with the input Zona using cbind function for insert the input value in the column. I hope this answer can help to other people

```
df <- eventReactive(input$csv,{
    req(input$csv)
    dff <- read.csv(input$csv$datapath)
    #The dataset is updated, eliminating rows and columns
    dfN = dff[-c(1,2,3),-c(1,2)]
    FC = dfN[,-c(2:26)]
    dfProc = data.frame(FC)
    return(dfProc)
  })
  
  datos <- eventReactive(input$zone,{
     newtable = cbind(input$zone, df())
   })


output$modified <- renderTable({datos()})
```